# Running expo on intellij react-native app

Tags: react-native, intellij-idea, expo

I cant figgure out how to run expo on intellij react-native app.
I created a new app(`File->New->Project...->JavaScript->React Native->Finish`) and then run `npm install expo`. The problem is when i run my app on android simulator i get

```
React Native version mismatch. 

JavaJcript version: 0.64.0 
Native version: 0.63.2
```

and

```
"main" has not been registerd
```

How can i deal with thees errors?
Do i need to downgread react-native version in package.json to solve the mismatch?

Answer (score 1):

See https://docs.expo.io/faq/react-native-version-mismatch/ for information on dealing with these errors.

Also I'd say that creating a new app with `npx --package react-native-cli react-native` and then adding `expo` to it as you did is not a right way to create Expo application. I'd suggest deleting the created app and using the [expo-cli](https://docs.expo.io/workflow/expo-cli/) to create the app: run `expo init` in terminal and then open the created project in WebStorm via **File | Open**. See https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/react-native.html#starting_with_existing_react_native_application

Comment: https://docs.expo.io/faq/react-native-version-mismatch/ dosent seem to work(i just want to run my app in android emulator...)

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend for you to follow the IntelliJ documentation closely: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/react-native.html#create_new_react_native_app

As far as I can tell IntelliJ creates a bare React Native app, and you are trying to add Expo on top of that.

If you are 100% sure you want to use Expo, you should start by creating an Expo app and then import it into IntelliJ.

Comment: I just want to run my app in android emulator(i'v seen https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup but it dosent help)

Comment: Expo and Android Emulator are 2 different things. Expo is a toolchain for creating apps - you can use it or not. If You end up using Expo to create your app you can download the Expo app and check YOUR app in it.
Android emulator is part of Android Studio: https://developer.android.com/studio 
Once you have installed Android Studio you can run any app in the emulator included in Android Studio.